# Cron being fired twice

Tags: cron

I am in a position where I have no ssh access and no admin access. A cron is set up to be fired every 5 minutes, but sometimes it gets executed twice at almost the same time.

Cron name is `ddg_automation_abandonedcarts`

### [image: Aoe Scheduler]

And below you'll see that cron is set up to be executed every 5 mins.
[image: Cron settings]

I know it sucks, but I won't get access. Any ideas what could potentially be causing this issue? Maybe this happened to you before? Any advice appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like many of your crons are executed twice in same time. 
This could mean and cron.php or cron.sh or scheduler.sh (from aoe_scheduler module) are mentioned two times in "crontab" server configuration. 
so firstly you should find - which file exactly is used to execute cron jobs. And then you can implement some custom code to prevent it to be executed twice. Or just to manage crontab configuration.

If you can - as server manager to send you result of next shell command - `crontab -e` and post it here

Or there can be other reason of issue: if your server have 2 or more server nodes (working with load balancer or just having Admin and Frontend code instances on 2 different servers) and on 2 or more nodes you have scheduled tasks created.